# Guardar una instancia con diferentes datos en ArrayList

Tags: java

Estoy intentando guardar diferentes objetos de una misma clase en un ArrayList, a partir de una instancia a la que se le van cambiando el valor de las propiedades, no se si me explico. A continuación un código que ilustra lo que quiero hacer.

Clase Jugador:

```
package jugadores;

public class Jugador {
    private String nombre;
    private int puntuacion;

    public Jugador() {}
    public Jugador( String nombre, int puntuacion ) {
        this.nombre     = nombre;
        this.puntuacion = puntuacion;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public int getPuntuacion() {
        return puntuacion;
    }
    public void setNombre( String nombre ) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public void setPuntuacion( int puntuacion ) {
        this.puntuacion = puntuacion;
    }

} //class
```

Clase Main:

```
package jugadores;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    private static String player1     = "Pepe";
    private static String player2     = "Leo";
    private static int score_player1  = 100;
    private static int score_player2  = 92;
    private static Jugador player;
    private static List<Jugador> players_list = new ArrayList();


    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        //Jugador 1
        player = new Jugador( player1, score_player1 );
        players_list.add( player );

        //Jugador 2
        player.setNombre( player2 );
        player.setPuntuacion( score_player2 );
        players_list.add( player );

        test();
    }

    private static void test() {

        int size = players_list.size();

        for ( int x = 0; x < size; x++ ) {

            player = players_list.get( x );     
            tracePlayer( player );
        }
    }

    private static void tracePlayer( Jugador x ) {

        System.out.println( x.getNombre( ));
        System.out.println( x.getPuntuacion( ));
        System.out.println( "------------------" );
    }

} //class
```

Cuando se ejecuta esto, lo que quiero es que imprima los datos del jugador 1, y seguidamente los datos del jugador 2, es decir que en el ArrayList se guarde primero un jugador y luego el otro, y no acabe teniendo copias del último jugador guardado.

Para simplificar solo use dos jugadores, cuyos datos incluyo en la clase Main, pero tiene que funcionar con una fuente de datos que me va a generar un número indeterminado de jugadores. Como desconozco cuantos jugadores habrá por lo que no puedo crear una instancia para cada uno.

Comment: No estás creando dos jugadores, estás creando uno con `new` y lo añades a una lista. Luego a ese jugador le cambias de nombre y de puntuación y lo vuelves a añadir, por eso cuando imprimes te sale el mismo. Haz lo que dice @yoandypv y te funcionará (crear otro jugador con otra instrucción `new`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que lo que se guarda en el ArrayList es una referencia al objeto player, cada vez que cambiar player lo que haces es sobreescribir sus datos y en el ArrayList lo que hay es un puntero que dice donde buscar finalmente los datos. Si quieres usar el mismo identificador "player" debes entonces siempre, antes de ponerle los datos declararlo, sería asi.

```
    //Jugador 1
    player = new Jugador( player1, score_player1 );
    players_list.add( player );

    //Jugador 2
    player = new Jugador() //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    player.setNombre( player2 );
    player.setPuntuacion( score_player2 );
    players_list.add( player );
```

Comment: Adjunto links de como crear un Array en java http://lineadecodigo.com/java/crear-un-arraylist-en-java/

Comment: adjunto como insertar elementos en un Array en java http://lineadecodigo.com/java/insertar-elementos-en-un-arraylist/

Answer (score 1):

Debe hacer un segundo new, como te dijo el amigo antes, para que en la 2da posicion de la lista, exista un objeto nuevo, sino tendrás una lista con dos elementos que contienen ambas la misma referencia al mismo objeto que cambio de estado 1 a estado 2, y se quedó así la última vez que lo setearon

Agrega el new para crear una segunda instancia

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {

    //Jugador 1
    player = new Jugador( player1, score_player1 );
    players_list.add( player );

    //Jugador 2


    player = new Jugador( player2, score_player2 );
    players_list.add( player );

    test();
}
```